# How to call a function later at a scheduled time in ColdFusion?

Tags: jakarta-ee, coldfusion

`<cfschedule>` can only call an URL.

What can I use to call a function with some dynamic parameters later?

the only way I can think of is to call it the GET way with and populate the parameters in url scope:

```
./someAction.cfm?param1=xx&param2=yy
```

However, this doesn't work for me 'cause I will likely hit the GET limit for large, complex data.

Do I need to implement my own scheduler to call a function?

or... is there any simpler solution in CFML?  if not, maybe something in J2EE?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could set something up to write your parameters to a local file or even a database, then your scheduled task could read the information from there, do its thing, then delete the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You could fire off cfthread to do the processing, however if the activity is far in the future this would not work well.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could set up your function as a web service and then call it via cfschedule?

```
<cffunction name="something" access="remote">
   etc
</cffunction>
```

Comment: I just noticed the bit about the GET limit concern.  Is that the only reason you feel it wouldn't work?